# Win 7 freezes randomly

Tags: windows-7, freeze

like the headline says i´ve got the issue with my win 7 64 bit pc that it freezes suddenly

Furthermore I´ve got some more i dont know if this bugs relate to each other:

1. Sometimes my mouse bugs and got graphical issues
2. If i shutdown the pc after such freezes you can here noise from the speakers

This is what i tried so far:

Updated Mouse driver

Changed Port of the Mouse

Changed Mouse

Updated Graphic Driver

Checked RAM with MemTest

and i deactivated shutdown harddisk at the powersave menu of windows

If you need any further information just comment and i will put them online

Comment: Random freezes are often an indication of hardware problems. E.g. a CPU overheating (dust bunnies clogging up the cooling fins?) or a PSU not providing stable voltage due to age or because it's too small.

Comment: what happens when you press the CAPS LOCK key during the freeze? Does the light of the keyboard toggles or not? If yes you have a software issue, if not you have an hardware issue.

Comment: @Roland Smith i've got an 600watt PSU and i cant see that much  dust i cleaned it 3 months ago but i'll redo that thanks for your fast comments :)

Comment: @magicandre1981 i'll try it if the next freeze occurs

Comment: @magicandre1981 the light does not toggle so i guess it´s due to an hardware issue. Any further steps how to get which part it is?

Comment: check all 5 methods from scenario 3: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504#method3

Comment: @magicandre1981 disabling hpc in my bios worked fine for me so i got no more hardware caused freezes but i still have the mouse issues